# Please review the changes I made to this closed question.

Tags: discussion

I made a meta post about this some time ago, and today made some wording changes to the title and content. It's my opinion that [the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11373/what-political-motivations-were-provided-by-brexit-proponents-besides-these) wasn't opinion based before, but with these changes I think those who argued against my logic should be satisfied.

I'm not sure adding a small edit to [my old meta question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/a-political-motivation-expressed-by-the-public-in-a-public-vote-is-not-subject/2684?noredirect=1#comment4673_2684) will get fresh eyes on it for re-open voting, so I made this new one just in case.

Comment: Thank you - much better post-edits. Voted to re-open (and I was one of VTC votes)

Comment: I think these posts can be an answer to [this question](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes). if not, after awhile  meta.politics would have a large quantity of these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit your closed question, it automatically gets put into a reopen-questions queue, and you can also flag your question asking for it to be reopened if you want a moderator to look at it.

There's no need to make a post in meta about it.